# What is the minimum requirements to run Ruby on Rails (Can the OpenPandora run rails?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if I can run rails, ruby, and some kind of text editor on this palm sized laptop, which I would like to do because it would be very portable and easy to use. This is the OpenPandora: http://boards.openpandora.org/page/homepage.html

Comment: You *can* do this, but you are almost surely not going to enjoy it.  Ruby/Rails wants a fast processor and a 1ghz atom is not going to be fun.

Comment: By "not fun", what do you mean.

Comment: "Not fun" as in, it's going to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

I would ssh back into a desktop and just edit text from that device.  I program all the time with my eeepc that has similar specs.  I use tmux on my desktop and keep a session open 24/7.  Look into autossh for keeping persistent port tunnels to your desktop (for port 3000 or w.e. you run your rails server) and you can cleanly leave the processing to your desktop while text editting and using your browser from your device.